# Android have core graphics like objective C Core graphics?

Tags: android

I an trying to port a drawing algorithm from iPhone to android but the problems that i haven't find graphics method in android which is slimier to iPhone, please help.

Example: iPhone having a method drawInRect() but android haven't.
In iPhone they will get current context of drawing but we don't have same concept.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Android uses the `Canvas` API, which hosts all drawing calls ([SDK Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html)).  Every `View` object is passed a `Canvas` on which to draw its contents.  You can customize the output of any view by subclassing and overriding its `onDraw()` method ([SDK Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onDraw%28android.graphics.Canvas%29)) to draw whatever contents you would like onto that view's `Canvas`.